# Why is the waitUntil method protected for ElementsCollection?

Tags: java, selenide

As you can see in the documentation, the `waitUntil` method is protected for `ElementsCollection`:

http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.7/com/codeborne/selenide/ElementsCollection.html

This is not the case for `SelenideElement` for example:

http://selenide.org/javadoc/3.7/com/codeborne/selenide/SelenideElement.html

Why is the method protected for `ElementsCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea behind this is that it make sense to apply `waitUntil` + visible/disappear/hasText/etc. Condition combination for **single element**, but totally useless to **collection of elements** and potentially buggy.

There is no way to set how many elements should disappear or should appear while you are waiting, taking in account performance cost it may bring - that was the right decision.

Comment: When I asked this question, I was thinking about doing something like "wait until the collection size is superior or equal to x". But I guess It makes more sense from this point of view.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its possible to solve this with another custom condition, but as I said performance/stability may become a pain. so from testing perspective I think it better to wait for more strict condition and then (if still needed) go with `collection.shouldHaveSize(size);`

Comment: I didn't considered the performance issue, thanks for your answer.